# How to configure Wayfinder (MODx) for Bootstrap 5 Dropdown-Menu

Tags: modx, modx-templates

how do I have to configure the "Wayfinder" in MODx to get a Bootstrap 5 output. specifically for the "Dropdown Submenue".

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
              <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-md-0">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                  <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                  <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" href="#">Project</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">How-To</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
                </li>
           </div>
```

I think it has to be the innerTpl and the innerRowTpl. The normal (level 1 menu) works. Just not the submenu.
How do I have to configure that?

The Wayfinder call:

```
[[Wayfinder? &startId=`0` &level=`2` &outerClass=`navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-md-0` &rowTpl=`tpl_navigation-menu` &rowClass=`nav-item` &innerTpl=`innerTpl` &innerRowTpl=`innerRowTpl`]]
```

&rowTpl:

```
<li[[+wf.id]][[+wf.classes]]><a href="[[+wf.link]]" class="nav-link" title="[[+wf.title]]" [[+wf.attributes]]>[[+wf.linktext]]</a>[[+wf.wrapper]]</li>
```

&innerTpl and innerRowTpl is still blank.

Did someone have an Idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK,

here is the final solution. (For those who struggels with the Wayfinder-Stuff as me)

```
[[Wayfinder? 
&startId=`0`
&level=`2`
&outerClass=`navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-md-0`
&innerClass=`dropdown-menu`
&rowTpl=`tpl_row`
&parentRowTpl=`tpl_parentrow`
&innerRowTpl=`tpl_innerrow`
]]
```

**Chunk for tpl_row:**

```
<li class="nav-item [[+wf.classnames]]">
    <a class="nav-link" href="[[+wf.link]]">[[+wf.linktext]]</a>
    [[+wf.wrapper]]
</li>
```

**Chunk for tpl_parentrow:**

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown [[+wf.classnames]]">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" href="[[+wf.link]]">[[+wf.linktext]]</a>
    [[+wf.wrapper]]
</li>
```

**Chunk for tpl_innerrow:**

```
<li class="[[+wf.classnames]]">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="[[+wf.link]]">[[+wf.linktext]]</a>
    [[+wf.wrapper]]
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Wayfinder](https://docs.modx.com/current/en/extras/wayfinder) often confusing here unfortunately, please take a look at snippet documentation [diagram](https://docs.modx.com/current/en/extras/wayfinder/wayfinder-introductory-examples#diagram), it will help you to understand which chunks are used to form menu child elements.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the link. But I still don't get it. I like MODx very. But the Wayfinder-Thing is every time (I did it not every day) a really struggling and confusing thing.

Comment: The problem is, there is no example of the innerTpl inside this doc. With the parentRow I have gotten the result that the drop-down arrow is displayed. But it doesn't go any further. I can't get the drop down menu to open.

Comment: Ok, I still stuck with it. Did someone make a Bootstrap 5 menue (with Dropdown) with MODx and can give me a hint?

Comment: Wayfinder instruction provides @innerTpl explanation the same as example from above, did you fill it? What is inside? Alternatively you could use pdoMenu(from [pdoTools](https://docs.modx.com/current/en/extras/pdoTools) package), it's much more popular and faster.

Comment: I tryed everything, and change it back and force, back and force and switch it ... The result is in every case not right. The more I read about the more I get confused.

Comment: Please update this post with all chunks you use for Wayfinder, this is necessary for further testing